# android studio proguard confusion

Tags: android, eclipse, proguard

I remember from `eclipse` that when i enable `proguard` it convert all of my class name, method name and variable name to something meaningless (like class `a`, method `b` and so on), **but** in android studio when i enable `proguard` and generating `apk` then decompile it via `APKtoJava_RC2`, it show me all my class and it's code with meaningful names (just removed comments and white space:), so whats wrong with my proguard config?

in `build.gradle` :

```
release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

in `proguard-rules.pro` :

```
-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
    public *;
}
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keep public class com.mehdok.epub.EpubWebView$ObjectExtension
-keep public class com.mehdok.epub.EpubWebView
-keep public class * implements com.mehdok.epub.EpubWebView$ObjectExtension
-keepclassmembers class com.mehdok.epub.EpubWebView$ObjectExtension {
    <methods>;
}
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep public class * extends android.support.v7.widget.SearchView {
   public <init>(android.content.Context);
   public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart` solved the problem, i don't know why:)